# Why are my comments on ROS Answers disappearing?

Tags: ros, meta, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is more of a meta question, but: when I try to comment on an answer to one of my questions, then hit "add comment", the comment appears below the answer. But then when I refresh the page, the comment is gone like it didn't save or something. This makes it impossible to ask follow-up questions. Any ideas as to why this is happening to me?

Reading the [FAQ](http://answers.ros.org/faq/), it says that the karma requirement for adding comments is 1, and I have more than that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207089/why-are-my-comments-on-ros-answers-disappearing?/) by [Jordan9](https://answers.ros.org/users/22059/jordan9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2015-04-13

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Evgeny](https://answers.ros.org/users/149/evgeny/) on 2015-04-15**:
This is a test comment. Sorry, it was a bug, hopefully fixed now. Could you try please?

**Comment by [Jordan9](https://answers.ros.org/users/22059/jordan9/) on 2015-04-15**:
Seems to work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've filed an issue ticket https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues/114

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jordan9](https://answers.ros.org/users/22059/jordan9/) on 2015-04-15**:
Testing the bugfix...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, It has nothing to do with Karma I guess.. Even I cant add/modify comments. I think there is some bug.
Sorry..I am forced to write this as a answer because I cant add comments but I hope someone fixes this.

---

Originally posted by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) with karma: 1464 on 2015-04-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The same thing is happening to me.

---

Originally posted by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) with karma: 792 on 2015-04-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can only add comments to my own answers. (don't know about own questions)

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2015-04-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2